# Use the connection string stored in web.config through a web user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have created a web user control to manipulate my database actions, and I want to use the connectionstring stored in web.config .... the way I used before in a asp.net page( like deafult.aspx.cs) was to add

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

and then use the code below:

```
private string connectionString =
             WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pubs"].ConnectionString;
```

the problem is that I can't add `using System.Web.Configuration;` to my WebUserControl ... 
Is that possible to read data from Web.Config through a webUserControl?

Comment: I mean .. it depends on what? ... and why it's important in this site?

Comment: @vishal, I improved that .. thx for you hint ;) ... Do u know the answer of my question?

Comment: You can definitely use that in WebUserControl...What's the problem..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just have to add the assembly reference for `System.Configuration` and you can then use

```
private string connectionString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pubs"].ConnectionString;
```

It will always read the connectionstring from web.config (and not from the app.config of the project as you might think). If you want to use the `WebConfigurationManager`, you will have to add a reference to the assembly `System.Web`, but that should be already there in a web control library project

Comment: u are right ... it works in asp.net projects .. but i want to use it in a Web User Control project ... I can add this assembly reference but I can't use ConfigurationManager in my code! have u used it in a web user control project?

Comment: It works in any type of project, but you have to add a reference to the assembly (on the project references => add reference). Do you have intellisense for the class or does the connection string not load? What is your problem? The WebConfiguration class is in System.Web, the ConfigurationManager is in System.Configuration which might not be added per default

Comment: Thx , I added System.Web from .NET tab and now I can add using 'System.Web.Configuration;' ,but I understood that I can't use a code like 'private string connectionString =WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pubs"].ConnectionString;'in my web User Control ... because my web.config file is in another related peroject ...